# How a Translate Animation works: Android

Tags: android, android-animation, translate-animation

I'm trying to move a `RelativeLayout` using `TranslateAnimation`. Code I have written for performing the same is:

```
translateAnimation = new TranslateAnimation(0, 0, heightOfRootView-excuseContainer.getHeight(), currentYPoint);
translateAnimation.setRepeatMode(0);
translateAnimation.setDuration(500);
translateAnimation.setFillAfter(true);
excuseContainer.startAnimation(translateAnimation);
```

I'm trying to start animation from current y position of particular view
(I do not need to change x position of view)
But animation is staring every time from its first y point. How can I perform this action from    current y  position of view to desired position of view.

Here `heightOfRootView` stands for height of full screen,  `excuseContainer` is that view which I want to move with animation and `currentYPoint` is last y point of `excuseContainer`.

EDIT:
I there any Translate animation tutorial available. I searched for it but I din't found..

Thanks for your support.

Comment: What do you mean by "first y point"? Can you draw something on a screenshot of your app?

Comment: I mean position where view originally placed while loading app.

Answer (score 10, accepted):

The 3rd parameter of the `TranslateAnimation` constructor you are using is a delta value, so the starting point is calculated like:

`currentYPos + startingDeltaY`

Since you seem to be passing in a `Y` value that refers to the location of something on the screen, this delta value won't be correct.

Try using this constructor:

> public TranslateAnimation (int fromXType, float fromXValue, int toXType, float toXValue, int fromYType, float fromYValue, int toYType, float toYValue)

Like this:

```
new TranslateAnimation(Animation.RELATIVE_TO_SELF, 0, Animation.RELATIVE_TO_SELF, 0, Animation.ABSOLUTE, heightOfRootView-excuseContainer.getHeight(), Animation.ABSOLUTE, currentYPoint);
```

Comment: can we start the animation of a window from a specific point and open on the  screen?
 ex : a window opening from the point below a button, and covering the window below that button.