# In android How to Translate to an absolute Point in Screen

Tags: android, translate-animation

I have an Imageview and an ImageButton and want the Imageview to move to the imagebutton's position.

The Imageview and its location on screen

```
myAnimation1.getLocationInWindow(imagePos);
```

The Image button and its location on screen

```
ImageButton.getLocationInWindow(buttonPos);
```

To translate or move the Imageview to the Imagebutton I tried

```
Animation move = new TranslateAnimation(Animation.ABSOLUTE,imagePos[0],Animation.ABSOLUTE,buttonPos[0],Animation.ABSOLUTE,imagePos[1],Animation.ABSOLUTE,buttonPos[1]);
```

But it is not working. The translations are not seen on screen. Any help would be appreciated a lot!! Thankyou in advance.

Answer (score 1):

First, just in case you are not getting the right coordinates from getLocationInWindow, try getting the coordinates like this:

```
ImageButton.getViewTreeObserver().addOnGlobalLayoutListener(new OnGlobalLayoutListener() {
            public void onGlobalLayout() {

              ImageButton.getViewTreeObserver().removeGlobalOnLayoutListener(this);

              int[] locations = new int[2];
              ImageButton.getLocationOnScreen(locations);
              // x is locations[0];
              // y is locations[1];

            }
        });
```

Comment: Thx..I will try this. Also I wanted to know if Animation.ABSOLUTE does move the image from one absolute position to another right?

Comment: I haven't tried it yet, but I think so! (http://stackoverflow.com/questions/16727647/how-a-translate-animation-works-android)

Answer (score 0):

You did not set the duration and not even started the animation.

```
move.setDuration(1000);
imageView.startAnimation(move);
```

And then try to play with the attributes of animation to get the desired result

Comment: I did set the duration and start the animation..i just didn't show it here coz i wanted to just paste the relevant code.

Comment: In which method are you calling this animation? Because in onCreate method your views will not be drawn to the window..